# Getting ERR_BAD_REQUEST while trying to send message using Whatsapp Cloud API

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-cloud-api

I'm trying to send a confirmation message to the users using whatsapp could api.

Below is my nodejs code,

```
app.post("/send-confirmation", async (req, res) => {
    const { phoneNo, bookingId, name, tripType, origin, destination, bookedDate, bookedTime, carType, distance, estimate } = req.body;

    console.log(phoneNo, bookingId, name, tripType, origin, destination, bookedDate, bookedTime, carType, distance, estimate);

    // Prepare the message template with the booking details
    const postData = JSON.stringify({
        messaging_product: 'whatsapp',
        recipient_type: 'individual',
        to: [`91${phoneNo}`], // Phone number of the customer
        type: 'template',
        template: {
            name: 'booking_confirmation',
            language: {
                code: 'en',
            },
            components: [
                {
                    type: 'body',
                    parameters: [
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Booking ID: ${bookingId}`,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Passenger Name: ${name}`,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Contact Number: ${phoneNo}`,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Journey Type: ${tripType}`,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Pickup Location: ${origin}`,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Drop-off Location: ${destination}`,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Pickup Date and Time: ${bookedDate} ${bookedTime}`,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Vehicle Type: ${carType}`,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Total Km: ${distance}`,
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'text',
                            text: `Total Fare: ${estimate} Rs`,
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ],
        },
    });
    try {
        const response = await axios({
          method: "POST",
          url:
            "https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/" +
            '117505268034839' +
            "/messages?access_token=" +
            token,
          data: postData,
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        });
        console.log(response.data); // or do something with the response data
        res.sendStatus(200);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      }
});
```

My `booking_confirmation` is approved by FB. Below is the FB template code

```
*Booking ID*: {{1}}
*Passenger Name*: {{2}}
*Contact Number*: {{3}}
*Journey Type*: {{4}}
*Pickup Location*: {{5}}
*Drop-off Location*: {{6}}
*Pickup Date and Time*: {{7}}
*Vehicle Type*:{{8}}
*Total Km*: {{9}}
*Total Fare*: {{10}} Rs
```

Once the API is called, I'm getting the below error

> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
> code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'

Message is not getting delivered, What I'm doing wrong here ? Plz help